FloatingPointError: Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN. Training has diverged
I am trying to train a layout parser model with detectron2 to detect references from a image of a pdf. I have used Label studio for annotations and after completing all the steps and finally when I was trying to train the model using the below code, it return an error telling that Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN.
!bash train_bib.sh
Error is also shown below. Is there any action that I can take to solve this issue?
ERROR [04/20 10:57:44 d2.engine.train_loop]: Exception during training:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 138, in train
    self.run_step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 441, in run_step
    self._trainer.run_step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 232, in run_step
    loss_dict = self.model(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py", line 160, in forward
    proposals, proposal_losses = self.proposal_generator(images, features, gt_instances)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/rpn.py", line 436, in forward
    proposals = self.predict_proposals(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/rpn.py", line 462, in predict_proposals
    return find_top_rpn_proposals(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/proposal_utils.py", line 103, in find_top_rpn_proposals
    raise FloatingPointError(
FloatingPointError: Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN. Training has diverged.
[04/20 10:57:44 d2.engine.hooks]: Overall training speed: 788 iterations in 0:09:47 (0.7458 s / it)
[04/20 10:57:44 d2.engine.hooks]: Total training time: 0:09:47 (0:00:00 on hooks)
[04/20 10:57:44 d2.utils.events]:  eta: 12:10:34  iter: 790  total_loss: 0.8574  loss_cls: 0.2257  loss_box_reg: 0.4571  loss_rpn_cls: 0.02462  loss_rpn_loc: 0.09986  time: 0.7453  data_time: 0.0108  lr: 0.015784  max_mem: 4423M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Module_01/layout-model-training/tools/train_net.py", line 222, in <module>
    launch(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/launch.py", line 62, in launch
    main_func(*args)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Module_01/layout-model-training/tools/train_net.py", line 190, in main
    return trainer.train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 431, in train
    super().train(self.start_iter, self.max_iter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 138, in train
    self.run_step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 441, in run_step
    self._trainer.run_step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 232, in run_step
    loss_dict = self.model(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py", line 160, in forward
    proposals, proposal_losses = self.proposal_generator(images, features, gt_instances)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/rpn.py", line 436, in forward
    proposals = self.predict_proposals(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/rpn.py", line 462, in predict_proposals
    return find_top_rpn_proposals(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/proposal_utils.py", line 103, in find_top_rpn_proposals
    raise FloatingPointError(
FloatingPointError: Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN. Training has diverged.

I have tried annotating different datasets but the solutions are not working for me! Is there any action that I can take to solve this issue?

